# 3 month large breed puppy thinks it's ok to pee in the house

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

My 3 month 30lb large breed Poopy(not real name) can hold her pee. We spent one weekend constantly monitoring her pee situation, and she didn't have an accident once in the house. Then during the week, while at work, she peed in the house. And we come home to what seems like a river of pee with poop islands.

We tried to use pee pads but it did not work, mostly because I never used pee pads before and made a mess of the training.

Our options are:

- Get a dog walker who comes for 20 mins 3 times a day for Poopy ($60/day)
- Teach Poopy at to go pee in a corner using pee pads, then try to correct her 3 months later as she will be tiny horse sized.
- Suffer

First walk in the morning is at 6:30AM. I leave for work around 8:30AM. She has the company of my 9 month female 80lb dog(potty trained), and has a dog walker coming at around 2-3PM. I come back at 7:30PM and immediately take her out.  Then, I sleep near her crate in the living room, and get up at 11:00 PM, 2:00AM and then restart the day at 6:30AM.

So far I have been limiting the food intake to twice daily. My girlfriend thinks that this is not working out as there is still poop in the house, and thinks the Poopy is looking malnourished.

Comment: Do you not keep her in the crate during the day?

Comment: I can't keep her crated 15-20 hours a day, she will go nuts.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that?

Comment: What breed is it and have you started puppy training?

Comment: Presa Canario. No I did not start formal puppy training, I will start it after vaccinations are done.